# Update metadata BlockBlob in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have been trying to update the metadata to my BlockBlob using Insomnia.I have managed to clear the metadata using the header(param json is empty):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiSDy.png)

with the strToSign:

```
"PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Fri, 11 Mar 2022 09:24:07 GMT\nx-ms-version:2021-04-10\n/myaccount/search/file_6444\ncomp:metadata"
```

but if I want to update the metadata, sending x-ms-meta-ide:2021 in the header(param json is empty), it doesn't work, it returns the error: AuthenticationErrorDetail The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'XXXXXXXXX' is not the same as any computed signature.

The strToSign is:

```
"PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Fri, 11 Mar 2022 09:24:07 GMT\nx-ms-version:2021-04-10\nx-ms-meta-ide:2021\n/myaccount/search/file_6444\ncomp:metadata"
```

why it's not working?? Thanksss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your string to sign to:

```
PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Fri, 11 Mar 2022 09:24:07 GMT\nx-ms-meta-ide:2021\nx-ms-version:2021-04-10\n/myaccount/search/file_6444\ncomp:metadata
```

Essentially the issue is that the headers must be alphabetically sorted in the string to sign so the order of the headers would be `x-ms-date`, `x-ms-meta-ide` and then `x-ms-version`.

For more details, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#constructing-the-canonicalized-headers-string.